# If there are two longest chains possible in an organic compound and both have the same number of substituents, how do we decide the parent chain?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Is the parent chain in the above case determined by atomic mass, alphabetical preference or any other rule?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If two longest chain are possible with same number of side chain in both of them, then we consider sum of locants of the side chain. The longest chain in which the sum of locants of the side chain is least is taken into consideration.

Comment: If the sum of the locants is also same, then?

Comment: In that case alphabetical order is follwed..

Comment: Alphabetical order in what sense?

Comment: This is incorrect; we determine the point of first difference of locants between the two possible chains, and prefer the smallest number: https://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_933.htm#ID_73zo0o

Comment: This answer is wrong. See also [IUPAC nomenclature: "Smallest sum of locants"?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27095/103369)