# Nomenclature of an alkyne with bromo and hydroxy substituents

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

### [image: Compound to be named]

Is the IUPAC name of above compound 7,7-dibromo oct-5-yn-4-ol or 2,2 dibromo oct-3-yn-5-ol ?

I understand that the former name is given keeping in mind -OH as the functional group but by giving the latter name we will have the least sum of locants (ie, following lowest sum rule) .

When should the lowest sum rule be dropped ?
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Daily dose of pedantry from me: Alkynes shouldn't be depicted as being bent like that.

Comment: The _smallest sum of locants_ rule does not exist in the IUPAC recommendations. The application of this ‘rule’ can lead to wrong results [in many instances](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/28009/7951).

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the relevant criteria for the numbering are:

1. lower locants for suffixes (here: ‘ol’)
2. lower locants for multiple bonds (here: ‘yne’)
3. lower locants for prefixes (here: ‘bromo’)

The corresponding subsection of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (c) principal characteristic groups and free valences (suffixes);
>
> (…)
>
> (e) saturation/unsaturation:
>
> (i) low locants are given to hydro/dehydro prefixes (…) and ‘ene’ and ‘yne’ endings;
>
> (ii) low locants are given first to multiple bonds as a set and then to double bonds (…);
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (…)

Therefore, the correct name for the compound given in the question is ‘7,7-dibromooct-5-yn-4-ol’ (not ‘2,2-dibromooct-3-yn-5-ol’) since the locant ‘4’ for the suffix ‘ol’ is lower than ‘5’.

[image: 7,7-dibromooct-5-yn-4-ol]