# Naming a hydrocarbon chain with multiple substituents equidistant from both terminals

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons

Does the substituent that comes alphabetically first take precedence, or do we look for the next nearest substituent, or is it a combination of both?

[image: this is the compound I am trying to name]

Comment: You mean from both ends?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decide at which end to start the numbering of the parent chain when the options for locant sets are the same?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76210/how-to-decide-at-which-end-to-start-the-numbering-of-the-parent-chain-when-the-o)

Comment: @Mithoron yes I do

Comment: @jerepierre thanks for the link, but I didn't find an answer there

Answer (score 1):

The substituents in the compound that is given in the questions are not equidistant from both ends.

Numbering from left to right yields the name 5-bromo-3-chloro-7,8-diethyl-2,9-dimethyldecane (i.e. the locant set ‘2,3,5,7,8,9’), whereas numbering from right to left yields the name 6-bromo-8-chloro-3,4-diethyl-2,9-dimethyldecane (i.e. the locant set ‘2,3,4,6,8,9’).

Concerning numbering, the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

Note that Rule f takes precedence over Rule g.

Furthermore,

> **P-14.3.5** Lowest set of locants
>
> The lowest set of locants is defined as the set that, when compared term by term with
> other locant sets, each cited in order of increasing value, has the lowest term at the first
> point of difference; (…)

Therefore, the example is named as **6-bromo-8-chloro-3,4-diethyl-2,9-dimethyldecane** rather than 5-bromo-3-chloro-7,8-diethyl-2,9-dimethyldecane since the locant set ‘2,3,4,6,8,9’ is lower than ‘2,3,5,7,8,9’.